# What does the dollar sign point to in this particular perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

```
/AA[.<]$]ER/
```

I came across this while running through some regex patterns online, but unable to break it down.

I initially thought it would be normal EOS, but those additional characters, don't make sense.

Comment: Was the multiline flag enabled?

Comment: No, it wasn't enabled

Comment: FWIW a regex like that can be more readable by using `/x` and braces. `m{ AA [.<] $] ER}x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a mistake by the author, but `$]` is treated as special variable here. Specifically, it is an alias of the variable `$OLD_PERL_VERSION` which contains the version of perl encoded as number, e.g. `5.020002` in my system (corresponding to version number 5.20.2). So that value is inserted in the regex and it is matched literally. So for example, in my system, the above regex will only successfully match against strings that contain the substring `AA.5.020002ER` or `AA<5.020002ER`.

Comment: `$OLD_PERL_VERSION` is a bit of a mess. I'm not sure when it appeared, but apparently [it was documented but didn't exist until 5.20](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.20.0/perldelta.html). It has been [discouraged in 5.24](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html#Documentation). I'd recommend pretending it never existed.

Answer (score 2):

$] is a special variable that returns the Perl version number. Special variables can occur in regexes.